# NSNotificationCenter applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification not working iOS 9

Tags: xcode, nsnotificationcenter, viewwillappear, ios9

I'am trying to call a function when the app com back to Foreground by applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. I have it in iOS 8 and iOS 7 and it works well. But not in iOS 9 ? It docent call first time you open the app

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:)
 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
 object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]]; 

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

//stuff

}
```

It is every notification center that is not calling at startup...

Comment: You might want to register in viewDidLoad instead.
Also, try to pass nil instead of `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in your object: argument

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem and for me it worked to move the addObserver code to awakeFromNib. Another solution could be to add a delay to the addObserver as in the example below:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Apple Foundation update for NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter)

This is what you need,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { note in
    self.applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification(note)
}
```